# why do i get java.io.IOException: Stream closed?

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to download a zip file but I get a **Stream Closed Exception**.
When i use using swing gui it get this erro but if i use console there is no problem.
Why do I get this exception? How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination.getPath());
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int count;

while ((count = in.read(b)) >= 0) {
    out.write(b, 0, count);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Download is finished");
} catch (HttpUnauthorizedException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proxy or Server Authentication Required");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

**this is stack trace**

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.available(PlainSocketImpl.java:428)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:217)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:321)
at weblogic.net.http.KeepAliveStream.read(KeepAliveStream.java:86)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
at be.azvub.ext.bcfidownloder.Download.downloadZipFile(Download.java:130)
at be.azvub.ext.bcfidownloder.Download.authorize(Download.java:91)
at be.azvub.ext.bcfidownloder.BcfiDownloadPanel$4.mouseClicked(BcfiDownloadPanel.java:110)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:212)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5520)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3129)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3901)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
at be.azvub.webutil.gui.WebEventQueue.dispatchEvent(WebEventQueue.java:34)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the exception?

Comment: stack trace please

Comment: I get exception here:
`while ((count = in.read(b)) >= 0) {
    out.write(b, 0, count);
}`

Comment: I did add stack trace: please see above

Comment: I use Weblogic, can it be from Weblogic?

Comment: Could you add line numbers to your code snippet please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception usually means the connection was closed abruptly. I would look at the logs on the server to see if there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

it can be due to JVM delays, It can be caused because of unix/linux operating system's random number generator. You should replace it with /dev/./urandom

This link has more details on it.

http://devcorn.com/java-io-ioexception-stream-closed-no-available-router-to-destination/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when removed this tag of Primefaces from my xhtml.

```
<p:media ...
```

source

> ```
> http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml
> ```