# Why do I get java.io.IOException: Stream Closed? (java 7)

Tags: java, file-upload, inputstream

I try save uploaded file as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214223/4518012) using `Files.copy(inputStream, path to file,replace existing)`

Here is method that throw exception

```
    public void handleAudioUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile audio = event.getFile();
    try (InputStream audioInStream = audio.getInputstream();) {
        MP3Util util = new MP3Util(audioInStream);
        Map<String, String> tags = util.getAudioTags();
        System.err.println(tags);
        System.err.println(webAppPath);

        Date currentDate = new Date();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        String[] arr = currentDate.toGMTString().split(" ");
        String target = arr[2] + "/" + arr[1] + "/" + arr[0];

        Path mainPath = Paths.get(webAppPath + userFiles + audioFiles + "/"
                + target + "/" + audio.getFileName());
        mainPath = Files.createDirectories(mainPath);
!!!Line 43!!!       Files.copy(audioInStream, mainPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These create all folder and file but file is empty/broken

And my exception

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
at trial.jee.j2eeapp.services.servlets.AudioUploader.handleAudioUpload(AudioUploader.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:290)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:751)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:927)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:118)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:70)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:120)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:226)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think that problem is [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968987/4518012) but I don't know how fix it.

Comment: how did you implement the `UploadFile.getInputStream()`? could you upload the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that exception because the stream is closed.

The stream is closed because some code closed it before your call to `Files.copy()`.

Given that it isn't closed in the code you posted, but that you passed the stream to `MP3Util`'s constructor, we can safely conclude that this constructor, or the method `getAudioTags()` that you call right after, has closed the stream.

Unless of course `audio.getInputstream()`returns a stream that is already closed.

If Mp3Util is the culprit, then the potential fixes are:

- stop using it, since it seems it's only there to print debugging statements to System.err
- reopen the stream once you have used in Mp3Util.

Comment: you have repeated the OP problem in your own words. His question is **"but I don't know how fix it."**

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I invoke `close` in `getAudioTags` method.