# Java run time error on shell script in pentaho

Tags: bash, shell, pentaho

I have a script in pentaho where it gets values like process id and few variables from the successful execution of previous job and write it as a file name into another location based on the process id and variable. While the shell script is being executed, it is throwing below run time error only few times. Please help.

```
ERROR 21-07 03:27:26,604 - Shell_Create_Trigger_File - (stderr) java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.util.StreamLogger.run(StreamLogger.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

"**(stderr) java.io.IOException: Stream closed**" usually happens if there is an abrupt closing of the connection or data connection is getting lost. You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968611/why-do-i-get-java-io-ioexception-stream-closed).

Also there could be multiple reasons like slow network, pdi process getting killed in the middle. But answer to your question can be broad. As you said the error is happening only few times, i suggest you look into the server you are running the code.

Hope it helps :)